# Can I export a question to other community?

Tags: feature-request, questions, community-user

I posted a question, but someone suggested me to move it to another community.

Is there some functionality that permit me to move the question to another community or do I have to copy and paste in order to accomplish that?

Comment: See also [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) on Meta Stack Exchange.